# Run single test with RubyMine

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, selenium, webdriver, rubymine

I´m using Selenium IDE and the export function to generate Ruby/WebDriver tests which I then extend step by step so that I end up with a couple of test methods per class.

I would like to run just one single test method from that class, but I don´t find an option within RubyMine to do so.

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

What works for me (rspec, minitest) is placing the cursor in the test case I want to run, or in the beginning of the file if I want to execute all tests within that file, and hitting `Shift + F10`.

Please consult the `Run` menu as well for further options.

Comment: When I open the run-menu, it offers me to run the whole class and the shortcut for this is Shift + F10, so your proposal is not working for me. :-(

Comment: This changes dynamically, at least in my case. If I place the cursor over a single test case, i.e. on the definition of `should 'whatever' do`, then it only executes this should (or context). You can also see this effect in the output window where the generated command specifies a `--name` param along with whatever your cursor is on.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the test class hast to *end* with "Test".